# for loop replacing all previous items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I'm trying to create a series of dates based on an array of weeks.

There are four weeks with 5 days each, each week being an object containing the weeknumber and an array of 5 days - the days being objects that contain the day and the date.

`weeks[0].days[0].day` would return Monday, for example.

I use LuxonJS to generate the date based on the weeknumber and day in the week using the function `generateDate(weekNr, dayNr)`.

To fill the `date` value in the weekday items, I've tried the following:

```
for(x = 0; x <= weeks.length; x++){
   for(y = 0; y <= weeks[x].days.length; y++){
      weeks[x].days[y]['date'] = generateDate(weeks[x].weekNr, y)
   }
}
```

However, for some reason the days every week now get filled with the dates of the last week, so `weeks[0].days[4].date` would return the exact same date as `weeks[3].days[4].date`. In other words - apart from the week number, the 4 weeks become identical.

If I log the dates in the for-loop, they all appear correctly, so it seems they get replaced each time the first for-loop repeats. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't find `generateDate` in the Luxon docs. Can you provide it? Also, what is the week numbering you use? ISO 8601 standard? Where is the year taken into account?

Comment: The year is also part of the week object but it seemed irrelevant for this particular question.

the generateDate function is a function I declared elsewhere in the code, it does the following:

`dateTime.fromISO(weekYear+ "-W" + weekNr).startOf("week").plus({days: dayNr}).toFormat("DD");` 

The generating date part doesn't seem to be the problem, like I said when I log the date after every loop it appears correctly in the console (e.g. 20 different dates)

Comment: That last phrase really is an indication that the problem is *not* in the loop, but is already there before the loop starts. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is probably related to how you built the original `weeks` array. It looks like you assigned the *same* object to all four entries in `weeks`, instead of creating a *new* object for each entry.

Then when you run that nested loop, you will be mutating the *same* object for each iteration of the outer loop. So make sure to create a new object each time you assign (or push) an object to the `weeks` array.

---

As a side note, here is how I would do it in vanilla JavaScript:

```js
function getWeekDays(year, weekNr) {
    let dt = new Date(year, 0, 4); // 4 January is always in week #1
    // Get Sunday before the start of the week
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - (dt.getDay() || 7) - 7 + weekNr * 7);
    return {
        weekNr,
        days: Array.from({length: 5}, () => {
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1); // Increment date
            return { 
                day: dt.toLocaleDateString("en", { weekday: 'long'}), 
                date: dt.toLocaleDateString("en-SE")
            };
        })
    };
}

function getMonthDays(year, firstWeek, numWeeks) {
    return Array.from({length: numWeeks}, () => getWeekDays(year, firstWeek++));
}

// Example creation of the weeks array
let weeks = getMonthDays(2022, 9, 4);
console.log(weeks);
```